# Fire additional jQuery after ajax load

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a system that was not originally developed by me and I am not nearly as familiar with jQuery as the original developers.

They have an AJAX call bound to a click as follows in a .js file:

```
$('.edit-btn').bind('click', function(e) {
*** AJAX stuff here ***
});
```

I'm trying to get the page so that this AJAX fires without any user input in a specific scenario. I have done this part successfully - if PHP detects certain conditions then this is inserted as script in the HTML file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#project-costs').find('.edit-btn').click();
});
```

What I need to do next is fire an additional jQuery command once the AJAX content has loaded:

```
    $('#taskList').find(".steps-toggle").last().click();
```

I've tried a few approaches to this but I haven't got it to work properly, including:

- Nesting the command in ('#taskList').ready
- Putting it inside an ajaxComplete thing
- Adding the line to the bottom of the AJAX function - this actually works but then it fires the additional command EVERY time, when I only want it in those certain circumstances.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried jQuery's ajax Success function?
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: `$.ajax(...).done(function(){$('#taskList').find(".steps-toggle").last().click();});` But instead of triggering event, you'd have better to call a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by changing the ajax action to a function (i.e. the click bind called the function rather than running raw code). I included an argument for this function which determined whether or not it should execute the additional code or not. When called in 99% of cases, the additional code is not executed - and in that special scenario, I pass a different argument and it works.

Answer (score 1):

try as follows:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST', // GET/POT 
    url: rootURL, //Servre URL

        success: function(){
             $('#taskList').find(".steps-toggle").last().click(); //on success
        },
        error: function(){
            // on failure
        }
    });
```

[Ajax Example](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)